# Why does Facebook FB.logout() execute only once?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

Im using Facebook login plugin.When  my status is connected,

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
alert(response.status);
});
```

the event handler runs each time I refresh the page.
But when i logout

```
FB.logout(function(r){alert(r.status);});
```

The logout function and the event(auth.authResponseChange) handler runs only once.When i reload the page again it doesnt run anymore.
My guestion is why Facebook implements these functions different or im doing anything wrong?

Comment: `FB.logout` needs a valid user access token to work. And maybe after logging out the authResponse just doesn’t change any more …?

Comment: thanks yes this can be the reason